# DB access error after upgrade to laravel 5.8

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5.8

I upgrade laravel to 5.8 from 5.3 using [laravelshift](https://laravelshift.com/) one step at a time and tested each upgrade e.g

- Upgrade to 5.4, tested
- Upgrade to 5.5, tested
  ...
- Upgrade to 5.8, tested

but when I deploy it on the server, Linode Server with Cpanel setup, and I select php7.2 in the Mutiphp Manager for this website.

Now this works perfect on local envoirnment in homestead, but on live I get the the db error 'Access denied for user 'homestead'@'localhost' (using password: YES)'.

I also tried to connect to DB using mysql command line tool, and it works using the same password. I also changed the password in cpanel and try with new password. nothing is working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Changing the password to something simpler e.g only numbers & numeric characters no special characters like `#` or `(` etc worked for me.

The complex password which include special characters worked for me using the `mysql` tool in command line, but would through error when I run `php artisan install` or run my code in browser `http://my-project.dev`

Comment: +1 This is the most correct answer. # char is creating a problem with 5.8
it can also fix, wrap password from the double quote `DB_PASSWORD="xxxx#"`

Answer (score 4):

Even though OP has found a solution by using a password without special characters the real reason for this issue is Laravel 5.8 uses the new `phpdotenv` package which treats `#` symbol as start of comment.

From Laravel 5.8 upgrade guide.

> the # character in an unquoted value will now be considered a comment instead of part of the value.
>
> To preserve the previous behavior, you may wrap the environment values in quotes:

Answer (score 0):

you may not have homestead named database in your server. Create database first and then try to connect.

Comment: No, the db name, usename, and password is all correct. I connected using mysql command line tool and it works.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue when i first used mariadb, maybe, this article keeps the solution for your problem.

Look here: https://superuser.com/questions/603026/mysql-how-to-fix-access-denied-for-user-rootlocalhost